# White rectangle background when i scroll SharePoint Modal Dialogbox

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, visual-studio, modal-dialog

I'm facing a strange issue. Couldn't find the solution for this on the internet. I'm using a SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog in a SharePoint web part.

Issue: When this dialog box is displayed and i scroll on the page. A white rectangle background is displayed while scrolling. Below is my JavaScript code.

```
function addNewSubType() {
    var optionsAddSubType = {
        url: "../Pages/addSubmittalType.aspx?district=" + $(".districts").val(),
        title: "Add New Submittal Type",
        allowMaximize: true,
        showClose: true,
        dialogReturnValueCallback: dialogCallbackAddNewSubmittalType
    };

    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(optionsAddSubType);       
}

function initForm() {
    $("#AddSubTypeBT").button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-plusthick"} }).click(function (e) {
        addNewSubType();
        e.preventDefault();
    });   

}
```

[image]

Environment: SharePoint 2010, IE8

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks All